# Smoothly increase the size of an image with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a few images that will overlap each other on the page.  I want one of these elements to slowly get bigger based on some event.

To do this, I'm using the jquery .animate method like so:

```
$('#right').animate({ "width": width + "%"}, "slow");
```

However, when I do so the image does get bigger but there's a moment where the image get's even larger before scaling back to the proper size.  It's not a smooth increase at all.

You can see [my full example](http://jsfiddle.net/AgentDiscount/7bEdh/), just be sure to click the Grow button to increase the size and see the glitch.

Comment: Which event, exactly?

Comment: When you have cached the **right** element using `var right = $('#right');` then why are you using the `$('#right')` again for the animation?

Comment: Firefox: Button "Grow" has no effect at all; Chrome: first "Grow" works as expected; 2nd grow sets the image to a size without animation then *shrinks* a bit with animation...

Comment: If older browsers aren't an issue, I'd use CSS scale and transitions, and just add a class on click. Much simpler and smoother IMO.

Comment: your example work, just remove `max-width: 100%;` from `.face`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7bEdh/17/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/7bEdh/5/

```
$('#grow').click(function () {
      var right = $('#right');
      right.show("fast");
      var width =  parseInt(100 * right.width() /right.parent().width() + 10,10);
      $('#right').animate({
          "width": "+="+ width 
      }, "slow");
      $('#text').html(width);
  });
```

Comment: Some explanation would probably make it easier for the QA to realize where they made errors.

Comment: @dualed ya, maybe even i think it is not a good solution, i'd prefer to use solution as in Adeneo's comment, using: CSS3 transform: scale(x); property

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend using the [jQuery Animate Enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) plugin so that it performs smoothly on mobile devices and computers that do not have good processing power.

Second, I would increment your width so that it slowly increases in size as you click the grow button.

```
  $('#grow').click(function() {
    var right = $('#right');
    right.show("fast");
    $('#right').animate({ "width": "+=" + right.width() * .10}, "slow");
    $('#text').html(width);
  });
```

**Example Fiddle:**

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7bEdh/19/)

Comment: Thank you for the link to *jQuery Animate Enhanced* - I did not know this.